# Does Firebase push-notification badge count increase automatic in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting remote push-notification from firebase. I am trying to get badge count in app icon.
In Firebase there is option to give badge count as bellow

[image]

As for now i dont have device to test. My question is if i put 1 as badge count every-time will it increment badge count automatically on app icon? if no then how to increment it using firebase.

Comment: answer below, **UserDefaults** is what you want to use. Very easy to implement.

Comment: Badge count is **definitive**, not **accumulative**. That means if you have a badge of 4, then you send another 1, the 4 will get replaced by the 1, not added. You have to store the badge count yourself and add the number contained in each incoming notification to get the accumulated number.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `UserDefaults` to keep track of the amount of notifications that come in

1- first register the badge count to `UserDefaults` with a value of `0`. I usually register on Login Screen in viewDidLoad with whatever other values that I need to register

```
var dict = [String: Any]()
dict.updateValue(0, forKey: "badgeCount")
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: dict)
```

2- when your notification comes in from Firebase to your app, update the `"badgeCount"`. Here is an example when the notification comes in to `AppDelegate`:

```
// this is inside AppDelegate
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    // A. get the dict info from the notification
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // B. safely unwrap it 
    guard let userInfoDict = userInfo as? [String: Any] else { return }

    // C. in this example a message notification came through. At this point I'm not doing anything with the message, I just want to make sure that it exists
    guard let _ = userInfoDict["message"] as? String else { return }

    // D. access the "badgeCount" from UserDefaults that you registered in step 1 above
    if var badgeCount = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "badgeCount") as? Int {

        // E. increase the badgeCount by 1 since one notification came through
        badgeCount += 1

        // F. update UserDefaults with the updated badgeCount
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(badgeCount, forKey: "badgeCount")

        // G. update the application with the current badgeCount so that it will appear on the app icon
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
    }
}
```

3- whatever logic in whichever vc that you use to acknowledge when the user has viewed the notification, reset `UserDefaults'` badgeCount back to zero. Also set the `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber` to zero

SomeVC:

```
func resetBadgeCount() {

    // A. reset userDefaults badge counter to 0
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(0, forKey: "badgeCount")

    // B. reset this back to 0 too
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

Information for [UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-number-over-your-app-icon-using-applicationiconbadgenumber)

Comment: This will work only if your application is in foreground while receiving the notification. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter

> Asks the delegate how to handle a notification that arrived while the app was running in the foreground

Comment: @KévinRenella if you notice I said “Here is an example...”. The question is about updating the badge count. My answer is to show someone how to easily increase/decrease the badge count. If I showed every single use case it would be outside of the scope of the question. I used this one example so that people can see it in action. Btw, the way you said “This will only work if ... “ makes it sound like the way I’m telling them to update the badge count only works while the app is in the foreground -it’s misleading. You should’ve said “The example will only work while the app is in the foreground”